# Sencha Touch 2: How to initialize controller of a package?

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a ST2.3 app in a workspace, which use a package composed of a controller and two views.
I can access the views without referencing them in app.js without a problem, but I can't access the controller and the events fired by the views of the package aren't catched by the controller.

I already tried to reference the controller by doing the following in app.js:

```
controllers: [
    'packageController', OR
    'packageController@package.controller', OR
    'package.controller.packageController'
    ...
]
```

None works and throws a "file not found" error.

Workspace architecture:

```
workspace/
    touch/
        ...
    STApp/
        ...
    packages/
        package1/
            src/
                view/
                    ...
                controller/
                    packageController.js
```

Note: The app is packaged for native android device with Cordova.

Any ideas ?

***EDIT:
I found this in the sencha.cfg of the package, maybe it is related and I have to somehow specify the controller folder ? :

```
# This is the comma-separated list of folders where classes reside. These
# classes must be explicitly required to be included in the build.
#
package.classpath=${package.dir}/src
```

Comment: By the way your profile picture is cute. :D

Comment: Per your edit... as long as you "require" the controller **AND** it's underneath the /package/src/ folder, you shouldn't need to touch that line in sencha.cfg

Answer (score 1):

So it could be one of a few things.

First, be sure you have configured the Ext.Loader in your app.js with the proper namespace/paths:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
        'Ext' : '../touch/src',

        //assuming "Foo" is the namespace
        'Foo' : '../packages/foo/src'
    }
});
```

**Also be sure to add your package to the "requires" array in app.json**.

```
requires : [
    'Foo' //name of the package from /packages/foo/package.json
]
```

---

Next, check the name of the actual class defined in `packages/package1/src/controller/packageController.js`. Sencha Cmd can be a bit finicky... the class name has to match the file name **exactly** -- and the fact you have "packageController" as the file name (in camelCase) throws a red flag for me.

So a real example might be `packages/foo/src/controller/Bar.js` in which you'd find `Ext.define('Foo.controller.Bar', {})`.

---

At that point, you should be able to use the following in app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    //...

    controllers : [
        'Bar@Foo.controller', //OR...
        'Foo.controller.Bar'
    ]
});
```

---

Finally you must also run `sencha app refresh` with Sencha Cmd, which will regenerate your bootstrap files.

Running your app in debug mode after all of these steps, you should see the network request for `packages/foo/src/controller/Bar.js` and (hopefully) it loads into your app.

Comment: Well I implemented everything you proposed, tried also to rename the controller but nothing works... As before, the views are referenced correctyl (I can create them with Slider.view.xxx) but not the controller. I still get the error message :
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/Slider/controller/Slide.js?_dc=1404743891644`

Comment: When you run "sencha app build" do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: No warnings and no errors... Does the controller have to be referenced somewhere inside de package ? Or does the package has to be built ? (even if I already tried this)

Comment: I did also a testing build (not native) and checked the generated app.js file. The views of the package are present in the file but not the controller.

Comment: Is the code for your app available anywhere? If not I can try to reproduce the issue locally...

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue when I was creating my first controller in st2. I just created it manually by making a new file and naming it properly thought it's the wrong way and most probably leads to situation you described.

Proper way is to use the sencha command to generate the controller.

Did you use it to create the controller? I think there are some hidden things in the framework and it won't recognize your controller. Sencha command modifies the bootstrap file (at least I think it does) when controller is created using `sencha generate controller <your controller name>` and then you can tell in the app.js that you have a controller like this:

```
controllers:[
     '<MyControllerName>'
]
```

Run the above command in your projects root folder and it should work.

Comment: I didn't use the command but it doesn't work with it neither. I think the problem is related to the fact that the controller is located in an external package. But I can't find any documentation for this... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Dar-Jee Well have you properly added the package path to your app.js file and refreshed the app with sencha command?

Comment: Yes I did but still not working, a package without a controller is not very usefull :|